# Convert Map<Integer, Object> to JSON with GSON?

Tags: android, json, object, dictionary, gson

Hee Guys,

I'm curious if it is possible to convert a Map to JSON and vica versa with GSON? The object that i'm putting in is already converted to a Object from JSON with GSON.

Object that i'm using looks like this:

```
public class Locations{
    private List<Location> location;
    <-- Getter / Setter --> 

    public class Location{
        <-- Fields and Getters/Setters -->
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you refer this http://kodejava.org/how-do-i-convert-map-into-json/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming you're using a `java.util.Map`:

```
Map<Integer, Object> map = new HashMap<>();

map.put(1, "object");

// Map to JSON
Gson gson = new Gson(); // com.google.gson.Gson
String jsonFromMap = gson.toJson(map);
System.out.println(jsonFromMap); // {"1": "object"}

// JSON to Map
Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, String>>(){}.getType();
Map<String, String> map = gson.fromJson(json, type);
for (String key : map.keySet()) {
    System.out.println("map.get = " + map.get(key));
}
```

[Source](http://kodejava.org/how-do-i-convert-map-into-json/)

Comment: I'll try and implement this, you'll here from me when I get it working or not.

Comment: Works, sorry for the delay. Almost forgot about it!

Comment: When you do JSON to Map, how can I keep the key still be Integer?

Comment: @Heaven change `TypeToken<Map<String, String>>` to `TypeToken<Map<Integer, String>>`, and change the type of `map` from `Map<String, String>` to `Map<Integer, String>`. Then, the type of `key` in the for loop changes from `String key` to `Integer key`. You can then use `map.get(key)` as in the above example. Hope that helps, let me know otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you just need to register the type so GSON knows what to do with it:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type integerObjectMapType = new TypeToken<Map<Integer, Object>>(){}.getType();
Map<Integer, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(1, new Object());

String json = gson.toJson(map, integerObjectMapType);
System.out.println(json);
```