# Mapping dynamic objects with Retrofit & gson

Tags: android, gson, retrofit

I have problems mapping json like this:

```
{
"data": {
    "id": 2, 
    "name": "Litecoin", 
    "symbol": "LTC", 
    "website_slug": "litecoin", 
    "rank": 7, 
    "circulating_supply": 57656657.0, 
    "total_supply": 57656657.0, 
    "max_supply": 84000000.0, 
    "quotes": {
        "USD": {
            "price": 77.9238663379, 
            "volume_24h": 334368162.90084, 
            "market_cap": 4492829637.0, 
            "percent_change_1h": -0.05, 
            "percent_change_24h": -1.5, 
            "percent_change_7d": -9.95
        }, 
        "EUR": {
            "price": 66.6913747769, 
            "volume_24h": 286169995.3231736, 
            "market_cap": 3845201724.0, 
            "percent_change_1h": -0.05, 
            "percent_change_24h": -1.5, 
            "percent_change_7d": -9.95
        }
    }, 
    "last_updated": 1533123370
}, 
"metadata": {
    "timestamp": 1533122956, 
    "error": null
}
```

}

As you can see; the object names in the quotes object are dynamic and i never know how much objects there will be in the quote object. I think the server should put this in an array but I have no control over the API/

Everything else gets mapped correctly, it's only the content of the quotes object that is null

Is there any way I can map this with gson and Retrofit?

What I've tried:

```
public class Quotes {
    //region variables
    private Map<String, Fiat> fiatMap;
    //endregion

    //region getters
    public Map<String, Fiat> getFiatMap() {
        return fiatMap;
    }
    //endregion

    //region setters
    public void setFiatMap(Map<String, Fiat> fiatMap) {
        this.fiatMap = fiatMap;
    }
    //endregion
}
```

What my service looks like:

```
Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Constants.BASE_URL)
                .client(client)
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());

 Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();
 client = retrofit.create(MyCLient.class)
```

Comment: Please add the Fiat Class too. And your logcat error.

Comment: Is Quotes root of Model?

Comment: Please read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29698754/7303452) and adapt.

Comment: Hamlet sorry but i don't need to map anything to json. I also have no logcat error, the object is just null and that's it

Comment: @saiedmomen: no, there's another object that contains the quotes object

Comment: Could you include the parent class too?

Comment: i edited my post, it now contains the full json output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a custom Deserializer for that class.

```
gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .registerTypeAdapter(Quotes.class, new MyCustomDeserializer())
                .create();

public class MyCustomDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Quotes> {

    @Override
    public Quotes deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
         // Your custom deserilizer here
    }
}
```

Then you have to set that `gson` as the converter in the retrofit builder

Comment: I'll check it out and mark as resolved if this solves my problem, thanks :)